# About the roots of the matching polynomial

Tags: graph-theory, polynomials, spectral-graph-theory

Can someone kindly give me an expository reference on matching polynomial and its roots? (there is a proof that they are always real?)

---

I saw these two related discussions,

- [Roots of matching polynomial of graph](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171688/roots-of-matching-polynomial-of-graph)
- [k-th largest root in common interlacing polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162056/k-th-largest-root-in-common-interlacing-polynomials)

Answer (score 7):

I really like that paper:

C. D. Godsil and I. Gutman. On the matching polynomial of a graph. In L. Lovasz and V. T. Sos, editors, Algebraic Methods in graph theory, volume I of Colloquia Mathematica Societatis Janos Bolyai, 25, pages 241–249. Janos Bolyai Mathematical Society, 1981.

Answer (score 5):

The best referrence is the following thesis

> [Investigations of Graph Polynomials](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~jhaglund/thesis/mirkoms.pdf)

By; Mirko Visontai

[Certicates for properties of stability polynomials
of graphs](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~kmorgan/Ranjie/Thesis.pdf)

[Graphs With Few Matching Roots](http://math.ipm.ac.ir/combin/publications/files/2012/PA1200017.pdf)
Ebrahim Ghorbani

[Characteristic polynomial and Matching
Polynomial](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~janos/COURSES/238900/ia/matching.pdf)